# Foreach iteration not working

Tags: php, arrays

I got some key values in an array variable. Here I iterate the array and execute it.

---

```
foreach ($key_details as $index => $value) {
   # code...
   $result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
   'Bucket'  => CONTENT_BUCKET,
   'Objects' => array(
      array('Key' => $value),
   )
   ));
}
```

---

Here each time I need to create an instance. If this possible to iterate like this

---

```
# code...
$result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
   'Bucket'  => CONTENT_BUCKET,
   'Objects' => array(
      foreach ($key_details as $index => $value) {
         array('Key' => $value),
      }
   )
   ));
}
```

Comment: `array('Key' => $value)` you mean `array($key => $value)` ? and does Object array contain another array or multiple arrays or directly keys => values ?

Comment: Only first variant would be work. In the second code you try add cycle to the `array`. Also you may create array of arrays with `foreach` before adding them to `deleteObjects` function.

Comment: there are number of values present in $key_details. here i want each record and put it in delete objects. When i use the last method i got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')' in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` inside an array declaration like that - hence your `parse error: unexpected T_FOREACH...`. Instead, though, you could simply create the data for `Objects` first, then use that for your `deleteObjects` parameter.

```
$objects = array();
foreach ($key_details as $value) {
    $objects[] = array('Key' => $value);
}

$result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
            'Bucket'  => CONTENT_BUCKET,
            'Objects' => $objects
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding `$result` all the time

```
$result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(....
```

dont you expact to create an array ?

like

```
$result[] = $s3->deleteObjects(array(....
```

or

```
$result[$key] = $s3->deleteObjects(array(....
```

you could also set the result after the foreach and in the foreach is a temp_object array...

and you have

```
array('Key' => $value)
```

may you want this to be like

```
array($key => $value)
```